# Single IP Registration Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ip

Hi How can i do this in wordpress User can Register in my site one time from one IP If anyone try to create duplicate account it will not allow. I cant find any plugin to do that. One IP one Account. 
I am using myCRED Plugin .. so when a user join they get point to do some activity ... if i cant blocked Register .. They can Register again and again and can get the product. As i give them some free point just to Register.
Anyone have any solution please.

I can save user ip in  `wp_usermeta` Using this Plugin Register IPs

Comment: Just to note that having two or more different users with the same IP address doesn't necessarily mean that someone is trying to create a second account!

Comment: Yeah .. i have no problem if user login from same IP ... but to register One user per IP
After they register .. they can login from any IP

Comment: No one know the solution .. so i think its a hard one  LOL